# Why am I getting multiple results for the same string, and why are they different

Tags: android, stringbuilder

Im looping through a SDCard directory, reading the text in each file, and writing the text to dynamically added textViews.
Each file contains line breaks, I think that it where the problem lies.
I've searched SO, and Google, tried some suggestions, and now my code returns and prints each text file twice. The first only contains the text until the first line break, the ssecond prints the text exactly how I need it.
Example text file test.txt

```
    This is a test.
    And I cannot make it work
```

The desired output is

```
    test.txt
    This is a test.
    And I cannot make it work
```

The first time the views are added I get

```
    test.txt
    This is a test.
```

The second time, I get the desired output. It does this with all txt files

Here is my code

```
    String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.BELIEVE/PushMessages/";

    // go to your directory
    File fileList = new File( sdcard );

    //check if dir is not null
    if (fileList != null){

        // so we can list all files
        File[] filenames = fileList.listFiles();

        // loop through each file
        for (File tmpf : filenames){

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tmpf));
            String name = tmpf.getName();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
            TextView title = new TextView(PushMessagesPage.this);
            TextView message = new TextView(PushMessagesPage.this);
            ll.addView(title);
                title.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            title.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
            title.setTextColor(0xff33b5e5);
            title.setText(name);
            ll.addView(message);    
                            message.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
            message.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
            message.setText(text);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `message.setText(text);` should be out of the while loop

Comment: Is your problem get solved?

Comment: Sunil, after I read your comment last night I examined my above code and it became evident that you were absolutely right. Thanks for the advice, I upvoted your comment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this.

```
for (File tmpf : filenames) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tmpf));
        String name = tmpf.getName();
        String line;

        TextView title = new TextView(StackDemosActivity.this);
        ll.addView(title);
        title.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        title.setTextAppearance(this,
                android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
        title.setTextColor(0xff33b5e5);
        title.setText(name);

        TextView message = new TextView(StackDemosActivity.this);
        ll.addView(message);
        message.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        message.setTextColor(0xffffffff);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        message.setText(text);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, this answer is 100% Working. When I get stuck, I try so many different things that my code gets all tangled. This is nice and clean, great Answer!

Comment: It should also be noted, that setTextAppearence(this, android.R.attr.textAppearenceLarge) only works on APIs 13 and down. If you are using 14 or higher it should be setTextAppearence(this, android.R.style.TextAppearence_Large)